# Whats the best way to update this reference data used in Spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, push-notification, amazon-sqs

I have a spark application which uses not so frequently changing reference data. this reference data is fetched from another REST endpoint. Currently I'm calling the API every 5mins to get the latest. I would like to get the latest immediately upon notification.
Whats the best way to update this reference data on immediate change?

Comment: It's impossible to say with the information you've given. Where (and it what) format is the reference data stored? Is there any other way to access it than by using the REST API?

Comment: Reference data is in JSON format. There is no other way to access it other than REST API

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pump your data from your rest endpoint into a Kafka.
2. Keep a small light weight consumer code in scala or java or spark  consumer 
   that checks for latest messages in kafka.
3. Once a new message is arrived you can submit your spark job.